# getopt_long() to parse more than one argument to a single option letter

Tags: c, getopt

I want to use `getopt_long()` to parse command-line arguments.  After reading the `getopt_long()` man pages, I have the understanding that `getopt_long()` only can parse one argument after an option. Is there anyway to use `getopt_long()` to parse this command line like this:

```
./a.out -s 127.0.0.1 2012 -u stackoverflow
```

To give the result:

```
ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 2012
username = stackoverflow
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
while (1) {
    int this_option_optind = optind ? optind : 1;
    int option_index = 0;
    static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"server", required_argument, NULL, 's'},
        {"user", required_argument, NULL, 'u'},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
    };

    c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "s:u:", long_options, &option_index);
    if (c == -1)
        break;

    switch (c) {

        case 's':
            printf("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
            if (optarg) {
                printf(" with arg %s", optarg);
            }
            printf("\n");

        case 'u':
            printf("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
            if (optarg) {
                printf(" with arg %s", optarg);
            }
            printf("\n");

        case '?':
            break;

        default:
            printf("?? getopt returned character code 0%o ??\n", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a `-p`/`--port` flag? Or just passing `host:port`, as is fairly standard?

Comment: Can you please show some code for this ?

Comment: ... It's exactly the same as your `-u` and `-s` flags.

Comment: But how can i make -s depending on -p, sow when i give argument -s I also have to give argument -p ?

Comment: @Kevin that doesn't really answer his question. What if it was something else like `--server=<server> --clients=<client1>...`

Answer (score 4):

The first answer is: nothing stops you from using or modifying `optind`. If `optind < argc` then `optind` is the index of the next common-line argument in `argv`, and otherwise there are no more arguments. So you can use that argument in your processing loop, but it's your responsibility:

- to ensure that `optind` is in range (`< argc`)
- to check whether the argument at `argv[optind]` is another option or not (i.e. whether it starts with a `-`)
- to increment `optind` so that the argument you've used doesn't get rescanned by `getopt`.

The second answer is: you should think three times before doing something non-standard like this. Although it might seem like a bit more typing, there are good reasons to use a more standard technique, like a `-p PORT` option. It's easier to document, less work to implement, and less surprising for users accustomed to standard command-line option behaviour.

Finally, you're missing a number of `break` statements in your example code, which is why `-s` will be reported as also being `-u`.

Comment: Nicely put.  An option instead of using `-p port` would be `-s server:port`.

Comment: How would you recommend reorganizing the command line options for a server/client problem? ie. synchronizing multiple instances of a video player where one is assigned the role of server, and the others are made to be the clients?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd call your program like this:

```
./a.out -s "127.0.0.1 2012" -u stackoverflow
```

you'd be getting `"127.0.0.1 2012"` as value for `optarg` in the `'s'` case.